# Error Web Scraping with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a simple web scraping program, but I can't even seem to download a simple set of pages and get their sizes.

Here is my code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor
urls = """reddit twitter tumblr instagram linkedin""".split()

def fetch(url):
    from urllib import request, error
    try:
        data = request.urlopen(url).read()
        return '{}: length {}'.format(url, len(data))
    except error.HTTPError as e:
        return '{}: {}'.format(url, e)

with Executor(max_workers=4) as exe:
    template = 'http://www.{}.com'
    jobs = [exe.submit(
        fetch, template.format(u)) for u in urls]
    results = [job.result() for job in jobs]

print('\n'.join(results))
```

In the command line I'm running

```
python scrape.py
```

but I'm getting the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "scrape.py", line 1, in 
>       from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor
>   ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures

What do I need to do to surmount this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python 3.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

> New in version 3.2.

Comment: Is there no backport to 2.7?

Comment: Can't hurt to try. Thanx!